# Problema evento onunload en IE y Safari

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer, safari

Lo primero hola a todos y gracias por vuestro tiempo.

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con Jquery Mobile y tengo un gran problema. Cuando se refresca una página todo el contenido dinámico que se ha generado de la página se pierde evidentemente, solo queda la plantilla HTML donde se ha generado el contenido dinámicamente.

Lo que estoy intentando hacer es que cuando el usuario intente refrescar la página le pregunte si realmente quiere hacerlo, ya que se perderá toda la información de la página, esto ya está implementado y lo pregunta cuando el usuario quiere hacer un refresco de la página.

Pero el problema viene cuando intento hacer una redirección de la página a la página de inicio. Funciona correctamente para Chrome, Firefox y Opera, pero no para Internet Explorer y Safari...

El código es simple:

```
window.onunload = function(e){

$.mobile.changePage("#login");
window.location.reload();

}
```

Lo que hago en caso de confirmación por parte del usuario de que quiere refrescar la página es redirigirlo al login y hacer un refresco, para "obligar" a que se cargue todo el documento, ya que si no lo hago me dejan de funcionar todos los handlers.

Bueno el caso es que esto me funciona bien en dichos navegadores pero no así en IE y Safari, parece ser que IE se pasa por alto la redirección que le pido y directamente me vuelve a recargar la página en la que esté el usuario, con el inconveniente de lo comentado anteriormente, se recarga la página sin ningún tipo de contenido dinámico.

Alguien sabe por que puede suceder esto?, Internet Explorer no te deja hacer ningún tipo de redirección o algo?. He probado hacerlo mediante window.location, window.location.href y window.location.replace y nada sigue recargándome la página en la que se encuentra el usuario en ese momento.

Alguna solución?

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: hay muchas versiones de IE... ¿la version minima objetivo sería? .. (tip http://caniuse.com/usage-table)

Comment: que funcione en la última versión como mínimo, después ya me pelearé yo para que funcionen en las máximas versiones posibles...jejeje

Answer (score 1):

Utilizando `jQuery` puedes en la misma definición del `changepage` definir el `reloadpage` que es especialmente lo que te interesa:

```
$.mobile.changePage(
  "#login",
  {
    allowSamePageTransition : true,
    transition              : 'none',
    showLoadMsg             : false,
    reloadPage              : true
   }
);
```

Si miras la [documentación](http://api.jquerymobile.com/jquery.mobile.changepage/) verás que hay varias opciones distintas en el `changepage`

El problema que tienes con IE y Safari seguramente viene en que no hacen exactamente lo mismo después del `changepage`.

Tu función `onunload` quedaría así pues:

```
window.onunload = function(e){
    $.mobile.changePage(
      "#login",
      {
        allowSamePageTransition : true,
        transition              : 'none',
        showLoadMsg             : false,
        reloadPage              : true
       }
    );
}
```

Sin añadir `window.location.reload();` te debería funcionar.

Con jQuery 1.4 o superior el `changePage` está deprecated y se utiliza [`pagecontainer`](http://api.jquerymobile.com/pagecontainer/):

```
$.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("change", "#login", , {
    transition: 'flow',
    reload    : true
  });
```

Comment: Hola Miquel, primero darte las gracias por contestar.
He probado tu código pero no me funciona, se queda en la misma página en la que hago el refresh, lo he probado en Chrome y IE y no me funciona en ninguno de los dos. Me estoy volviendo loco ya..., a ver si alguien más puede ayudarme a solucionar el problema. Un saludo.

Comment: Te sale algún error en consola (F12)?

Comment: No, no sale ningún error ni nada.

Comment: Qué versión de jQuery utilizas? a partir de la 1.4 está deprecated esto. He actualizado mi respuesta con la versión de pagecontainer.

Comment: Utilizo la 1.4.5

Comment: Nada, no hay forma de hacerlo funcionar..., estas funciones donde es el lugar correcto de ponerlas??, en el document.ready() o fuera del document.ready()??

Comment: Fuera.. Están pensadas para utilizar en eventos de `click` o funciones propias de javascript. ¿Por qué lo necesitas en un document.ready()? Si ya le estás preguntando al usuario si realmente quiere refrescar eso significa que puedes enganchar este código justo después de preguntarle no?

Comment: No, no es que lo necesite dentro del document.ready, las tengo fuera del ready, pero es por ver si es que estaba haciendo algo mal..., pero ya veo que lo tengo bien. Por lo que no entiendo por que no funciona.

Answer (score 0):

Al final lo he solucionado sin hacer nada en el evento onunload, ya que cada navegador "gestiona" de una forma este evento, unos si que te dejan cambiar la url y otros no. Así que lo más rápido ha sido en el HTML crear un script que en caso de que se intente cargar dicho HTML desde cualquier página que no sea el login, se vaya directamente al login... Con esto se han solucionado los problemas.